Bluepill rtc wrong time count
I have a problem about configure of the stm32f103c8 MCU rtc module. The rtc clock has been selected LSE which is on board 32.768kHz. The New cr2016 battery connected on the vbat pin. Program is simple but I'm having trouble with that. I only wants to test the rtc of this MCU so i only reads the value of the sTime registers. The problem is when i select LSE as rtc clock source , the second is counting wrong which is 1:3 ratio of real time seconds. İt is very slow. But when i select LSI as RTC clock source it works accurate than LSE. But it doesn't work when power off so i cannot select LSI.    I don't know the reason behind. All setting of the RTC is default. I did the same configuration at the YouTube videos but no luck. Can you please tell me the reason.
Ps. Looks like stm32 RTC application is a bit problematic. There are lots of problems about RTC configuration on the web. Why they don't care about it !
Thanks.

I forgot to tell. I did this video except LCD display. sTime registers are watching with ststudio software. Link : https://youtu.be/cG6tvK0tT2w?feature=shared

do not use a comment to add information ... edit the question and delete the comment

Problem Solved.
For someone who ever faced this problem , it was because of the weak solder joints. I tried every configuration and setting but no luck. After i decided to resolder 32kHz crystal the problem has been solved. But still missing a few seconds. I think crystal is bad. It has to be replace. I think the crystal has been damaged when soldering at the factory , im not sure.

You should be able to accept your own answer. That indicates to the site (and other users looking for questions to answer) that the problem was solved.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer
